# CakePHP Contains not working with Recursive

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-1.2, containable

When I try:

```
// Removed the limit to ensure that all of the group notes items can be found and collapsed
$recent_notes = $this->User->Note->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => 2,
    'order' => 'Note.created DESC',
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'contains' => array(
        'NotesUser', 'Poster', 'Comment' => array('Poster')
    )
));
```

It does not limit the output whatsoever - I get every related model. However, when I don't specify `recursive` as `2`, or if I specify it as `1`, I am missing the `Comment=>Poster` model.

**How can I get only the models I need?** Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive is ignored as soon as you set contain.

From the docs:

> The ContainableBehavior has a number of options that can be set when
>   the Behavior is attached to a model. The settings allow you to fine
>   tune the behavior of Containable and work with other behaviors more
>   easily.
>
> `recursive (boolean, optional)` set to true to allow containable
>   to automatically determine the recursiveness level needed to fetch
>   specified models, and set the model recursiveness to this level.
>   setting it to false disables this feature. The default value is true.

Make sure the array key is set as 'contain', not 'contains' as you've posted above, so like:

```
$this->Post->find('all', array('contain' => 'Tag'));
```

I'm also assuming that you're loading and attaching the containable behavior correctly. If you're having trouble, the documentation is [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Core-Behaviors/Containable.html#containable).

Answer (score 8):

To get only the models you need, use the [[Containable behavior]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html):

- set recursive to -1
- use `'contain'` singular, NOT `'contains'` plural, like you have
- make sure you're setting the `$actsAs` variable in your model: `public $actsAs = array('Containable');`

Everyone that I know sets `$this->recursive = -1;` in the AppModel... this defaults everything to recursive -1 so you don't ever have to set it again unless you want to include more data...and in those cases, I almost always use `contain()`, not `$recursive`.

Comment: Thanks again, Dave. Unfortunately for you, swiecki beat you to the answer, but know that if I could mark both of you as correct I would :)

Comment: We both kind of posted it exactly the same time :) It's happened before and it'll happen again, no worries.

Comment: Yah - always happens that way.  Garrett: Suggestion moving forward - mark the best answer, not the first answer.  It will benefit the StackOverflow community more than just marking whoever's first.  I'm not necessarily saying mine is - just a suggestion for future.  We're not in it for competition / to get rep - we're in it to help people! :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In this case it was just a simple syntax error that you both caught instantly, but I have and will continue to look for the best answer moving forward.

Comment: @Garrett This is 4 years ago, but I can't help but notice that Dave "answered Feb 29 '12 at 19:01" and sweicki "answered Feb 29 '12 at 19:03"... so Dave beat him by 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have deep association, for example
History belongsTo Warehouse and Warehouse belongsTo Company
and you want only Warehouse.Company, you can also use

```
'contain'   => array('Warehouse.Company')
```